# Visual Studio 2012 becomes corrupt when installing WiX 3.8.

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix

Visual Studio 2012 becomes corrupt when I tried to install WiX 3.8. This is what happens...
Following a successful WiX install I try to run VS2012 and get the splash screen followed by this error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation". Clicking on ok simply places me on the desktop. The only solution is to re-install VS2012. I tried un-installing everything and starting over several times but no luck. I cannot find any information on this exact topic anywhere online including WiX forums. Does anyone have ideas on what I should try next?
Rudy

Comment: I've been running 3.8 with VS2012 for a while without trouble. I haven't heard of this problem before, so here are just a few things to consider/verify if you haven't already. (1) Make sure you are using the latest stable vesion of 3.8. (2) What other plugins are installed in Visual Studio? (I use Productivity Power Tools, Style Cop, and Resharper without any problems.) (3) Perhaps try a Repair on Visual Studio after the WIX 3.8 install? (4) Does anything show up in your Event Log when Visual Studio crashes? (5) Which VS2012 - Professional, Express, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem after installing WiX 3.8. Basically even more problems as Explorer and other system application could not be started anymore.

The root cause was a change in the PATH environment variable which ended up to be more than 2048 chars and therefore the %windir% var was not accessible anymore.

Try to remove some unnecessary paths in PATH environment variable as described here:
https://superuser.com/questions/355594/windows-7s-path-and-environment-variables-are-corrupted

At least for me, it worked afterwards again.

Cheers and good luck